# .NET & Tab-Delimited files

Tags: c#, csv

How can I create and append to a tab-delimited file in C#?

Comment: show the code you currently have, thanks

Comment: You create and append it roughly the same way as any other text file. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.aspx

Comment: Try answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465016/exporting-from-a-dataset-to-a-tab-delimited-file/24275124#24275124

Answer (score 6):

Here's quite a nice (free) utility for working with delimited files in .NET http://www.filehelpers.com/

Answer (score 2):

Here is a fast and very easy to use library that allows you to specify the delimiter. It is hosted on CodeProjects.  This gives a matrix like access to your delimited file (e.g. a 2 dimensional array).

[CsvReader](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CsvReader.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, tab separated value files are some of the easiest to work with.  Some applications (like Excel) will sometimes wrap values in quotes, but for the most part you can read TSV files by splitting rows on the tab character (and possibly checking for the first and last character being a quote).  Writing them then, is even simpler - write a tab ("\t") between every field and a newline at the end of the row (or use a command that takes care of the newline for you, like writeline).

Comment: Until some ahole like me puts data with a ` "quoted text in between tabs" ` like that in the section you're trying to parse. And I see that the display system doesn't show that I did use an actual \t in my text, so you may need to drop to raw HTML to see it. But that's still my point, isn't it?