# How to write contents of multiple multiLine texboxes to one txt.file ? and make the contents appear as they were entered

Tags: c#

I have created 3 multi-line textboxes and I would like to write and save them to a .txt file. For example if I enter to my first textbox "John" on the first line and "Sakura" on the second line. Then if I enter "Bill" on the first line and "Sasuke on the second" to my second multi-line textbox and the same kind of text to my third textbox. I have a button to save it to a file. I would like the information in the text file to be shown as this:
 [image: this]

This is what I have so far.

Hope my question is clear.

```
private void btn_Text1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SaveFileDialog SaveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
    SaveFileDialog.Title = "Save As";
    SaveFileDialog.Filter = "Text File (*.txt)|*.txt";
    SaveFileDialog.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";
    if (SaveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(SaveFileDialog.FileName, FileMode.Create);
        using (StreamWriter objWriter = new StreamWriter(fs))
        {
            objWriter.WriteLine("Names: ");
            objWriter.WriteLine(txt_FName.Text);
            objWriter.WriteLine("-------------------");
            objWriter.WriteLine("Last Names: ");
            objWriter.WriteLine(txt_LName.Text);
            objWriter.WriteLine("-------------------");
            objWriter.WriteLine("Date of Birth: ");
            objWriter.WriteLine(txt_Date.Text);*/
            MessageBox.Show("SAVED");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you consider to use a datagrid and save to csv

Comment: Unfortunately I have to use textboxes.

Comment: What is the issue you are facing?

Comment: The issue that I'm facing is that I can't figure out how to write the entries to file the way the are being entered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple answer would be something like this:

```
    private void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
        saveFileDialog.Title = "Save As";
        saveFileDialog.Filter = "Text File (*.txt)|*.txt";
        saveFileDialog.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";
        if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(saveFileDialog.FileName, FileMode.Create);
            using (StreamWriter objWriter = new StreamWriter(fs)) {
                for (int i = 0; i < GetMaxRows(); i++) {
                    objWriter.WriteLine("\"{0}\"\t\"{1}\"\t\"{2}\"", GetText(i, 0), GetText(i, 1), GetText(i, 2));
                }
            }
            MessageBox.Show("SAVED");
        }
    }

    private int GetMaxRows() {
        return Math.Max(Math.Max(textBox1.Lines.Length, textBox2.Lines.Length), textBox3.Lines.Length);
    }

    private string GetText(int row, int textboxId) {
        switch (textboxId) {
            case 0:
                return textBox1.Lines.Length > row ? textBox1.Lines[row] : string.Empty;
            case 1:
                return textBox2.Lines.Length > row ? textBox2.Lines[row] : string.Empty;
            case 2:
                return textBox3.Lines.Length > row ? textBox3.Lines[row] : string.Empty;
            default:
                throw new Exception("Not a valid id");
        }
    }
```

But it looks like you are trying to save this in tab separated format. And the problem is when you write: '20" monitor' into the field and you get a "-sign in the middle. Perhaps the tab is enough as a separator?

This answer is just to fix the problem you mention, getting text from all textboxes like your output file. But i think you should try to find a better way to do this (perhaps a datagrid as suggested), and then solve the problems with invalid characters. Example for saving from datagrid: [Exporting from a dataset to a tab delimited file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465016/exporting-from-a-dataset-to-a-tab-delimited-file)

There are easier ways to save to a tab seperated file even with text delimiters and support for escaping characters that are invalid.

But since i dont know how this is going to be used i am just giving you a simple answer to your question, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some very crappy code you can start from:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string textBox1_Text = "";
        string textBox2_Text = "";
        string textBox3_Text = "";

        var list1 = textBox1_Text.Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray()).ToList();
        var list2 = textBox2_Text.Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray()).ToList();
        var list3 = textBox3_Text.Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray()).ToList();

        var largestListSize = list1.Count > list2.Count ? list1.Count : list2.Count;
        largestListSize = list3.Count > largestListSize ? list3.Count : largestListSize;

        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < largestListSize; i++)
        {
            var list1Line = list1.Count <= i ? list1[i] : string.Empty;
            var list2Line = list1.Count <= i ? list2[i] : string.Empty;
            var list3Line = list1.Count <= i ? list3[i] : string.Empty;

            sb.AppendFormat(@"""{0}""\t""{1}""\t""{2}""", list1Line, list2Line, list3Line);
        }

        System.IO.File.WriteAllText("your_path", sb.ToString());
    }
```