# c# send output to tab delimited file from a list

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [.NET & Tab-Delimited files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888385/net-tab-delimited-files)

I have a list that has 2 columns: FirstName, LastName.

I am not sure how to send it to a tab delimited file showing the headers.

I know I need to look through the list but not sure how to produce the tab delimited file.

My path to the file output is: `C:\emailfile.txt`

Comment: Already answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3134573/reading-writing-csv-tab-delimited-files-in-c-sharp and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888385/net-tab-delimited-files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [`FileHelpers`](http://www.filehelpers.net/) - you can use this library to create you tab delimited file.